# JavaFX : MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : media type not supported

Tags: media-player, javafx-2

When I try playing ***.mov*** file within my application I get the following error :

```
MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : media type not supported (file:///C:/videos/start.mov)
```

JavaFX Verion : 2.1

IDE : Netbeans 7.2

Platform : Windows XP.

Any idea about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Media you are trying to play is unsupported for playback in JavaFX, you need to convert it to a different type.

---

For JavaFX 2.2, has a limited number of supported [media types and encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes).  You will notice that .mov is not a supported container format for JavaFX.  It doesn't matter that Windows Media Player or other software on the machine can play it back - the format needs to be explicitly supported by JavaFX for it to work.

Additionally, on platforms like WindowsXP, additional external codecs are required to be installed on the system for playback of some formats (like MP4).

---

So what you need to do to be able to playback the video using JavaFX is re-encode it in a format which JavaFX is able to playback.  If you want to allow the playback on XP without installing extra codecs, then you can use a VP6 encoding in an FLV container.  You can (probably) convert your file to this format using [Wildform's encoding software](http://www.wildform.com/products/flix/flix_standard.php).  Or you could re-encode to MP4 if you don't mind installing extra codecs on the client system (e.g. by installing [DivX](http://www.divx.com/)).  A google search will turn up info on how to encode to H264+AAC in an MP4 container.

Note that for OSX or Win7 no extra codecs are required for playback of H264+AAC in an MP4 container (but in any case the mov container is not supported by JavaFX on those platforms either at the moment).

Comment: I have converted the mov video to mp4, but I still missing the video in the media player, When I run the application I get the sound without pictures! even so I can play the mp4 generated file by double-click. is JavaFX requires a specific mp4 file caracteristics?

Comment: Is the video in the mp4 encoded in h264?  Did you install the third party DivX software linked in the question on your XP box?  If not, did you install some other h264 decoder as described in the [JavaFX installation instructions for your version](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/release-documentation.html)

Comment: How can I know that the mp4 is encoded in h264. Yes I have installed DivX software. I want to add something, is that the app play an other mp4 video, but the one that I have converted not, so I think too that is sth related to h264, thanks